# How to send response error message from firebase-cloud-function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to send response error message from firebase-cloud-function

my code in cloud function

```
exports.registerUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return corsTool(req, res, async () => {
    const { mobile } = req.body;
    const data = {
      ...req.body,
      createAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
    };
    try {
      let queryMobile = db.collection("users").where("mobile", "==", mobile);
      const userMobile = await queryMobile.get();
      if (userMobile._size === 0) {
        await db
          .collection("users")
          .doc()
          .set(data);
        res.status(200).send(`save success`);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error This mobile number is not available.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  });
});
```

---

my code in client

```
const registerUser = () => {
      const link = 'https://us-central1-....../registerUser'
       try {
          const regis = await axios.post(link, body)
          console.log('success')
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
          console.log(e.message)
        }
}
```

but resualt in console.log() not show error status message "Error This mobile number is not available."

massage show this...

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

and

```
Request failed with status code 500
```

i need show message "Error This mobile number is not available."

thank you vermutch for help

---

Now I fix by doing this

if Phone number already used

```
res.status(200).send('Phone number already used')
```

and check text in client

```
if(regis.data === "Phone number already used") {
   alert("Error: Phone number already used")
}else {
   alert("Save success")
}
```

Is this a good choice?

Comment: You code is generating an error. Your code should log any errors so you can see what's happening.  Please go back and change your code to correctly log errors (in your catch block).  For example: `console.error(error)`.

Comment: Are you sure this error is thrown from your Firebase function? This error might be thrown from somewhere else. I suggest to change status code to different in your function and check if the error will be changed. If not you should look somewhere else.